# Can we express $\lfloor\frac{a+b}M\rfloor$ and $\lceil\frac{a+b}M\rceil$ in simpler terms? Eg in terms of $\lfloor\frac aM\rfloor, a\bmod M, b$, etc?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Can we express $\lfloor\frac{a+b}M\rfloor$ and $\lceil\frac{a+b}M\rceil$ in simpler terms? Eg in terms of $\lfloor\frac aM\rfloor, a\bmod M, \lfloor\frac bM\rfloor, b\bmod M$, and possibly other simpler terms?

I posted a solution, but I feel that my proof of my solution is long and tedious. Was wondering if someone might have a better/simpler solution/proof or suggestions on how to make my solution/proof simpler.

Answer (score 1):

*(If there's a simpler derivation, let me know.)*

---

Let integer division $//$ be defined as floor division, i.e., $x//M := \big\lfloor x/M \big\rfloor$ where $/$ is regular division.

---

A summary of $^{1,2}$ for floor division says that for dividend $x \in \mathbb R$ and divisor $M \in \mathbb R_{\neq 0}$, if we define the quotient as $q(x) := x//M = \big\lfloor x/M \big\rfloor$, the remainder as $r(x) := x - q(x)M$, and the Modulo operation as $x \bmod M := r(x)$, then these values of $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ satisfy

$$x = q(x)M + r(x)$$

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{if } M > 0 &\text{then } 0 \leq r(x) < M\\
\text{if } M < 0 &\text{then } M < r(x) \leq 0
\end{cases}
\qquad \equiv \qquad
\begin{aligned}
&0 \leq \lvert r(x) \rvert < \lvert M \rvert\\
&\text{and } \big(r(x) {=} 0 \text{ xor } \operatorname{sgn}(r(x)) {=} \operatorname{sgn}(M)\big)
\end{aligned}
$$

That is, the remainder $r(x)$ is either $0$ or has the same sign as the divisor $M$ (both are positive or both are negative).

---

## Derivations of $\big\lfloor \frac{a + b}{M} \big\rfloor = q + q' + \big[\!\!\big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert \geq \lvert M \rvert\ \big]\!\!\big]$ and $\big\lceil \frac{a + b}{M} \big\rceil = q + q' + \big[\!\!\big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert > 0 \big]\!\!\big] + \big[\!\!\big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert > \lvert M \rvert\ \big]\!\!\big]$

Let $a, b, M \in \mathbb R$ be real numbers, with $M \neq 0$, and define

$$
\begin{aligned}
q &:= q(a) = \big\lfloor a/M \big\rfloor
&r &:= a \bmod M = r(a) = a - qM\\
q' &:= q(b) = \big\lfloor b/M \big\rfloor
&r' &:= b \bmod M = r(b) = b - q'M
\end{aligned}
$$

By $^{1,2}$, these values satisfy

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{if } M > 0 &\text{then } 0 \leq r, r' < M\\
\text{if } M < 0 &\text{then } M < r, r' \leq 0
\end{cases}
\qquad \equiv \qquad
\begin{aligned}
&0 \leq \vert r^* \rvert < \lvert M \rvert\\
&\text{and } \big(r^* {=} 0 \text{ xor } \operatorname{sgn}(r^*) {=} \operatorname{sgn}(M)\big)\\
&\text{for } r^* \in \{r, r'\}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

### Proof of $\big\lfloor \frac{a + b}{M} \big\rfloor = q + q' + \big[\!\!\big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert \geq \lvert M \rvert\ \big]\!\!\big] \qquad \text{See}\ ^3$

We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big\lfloor \frac{a + b}{M} \Big\rfloor
&=\Big\lfloor \frac{qM + r + b}{M} \Big\rfloor\\
&= \Big\lfloor q + \frac{r + b}{M} \Big\rfloor\\
&= q + \Big\lfloor \frac{r + b}{M} \Big\rfloor &&(*1)\\
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{a}{M} \Big\rfloor + \Big\lfloor \frac{(a \bmod M) + b}{M} \Big\rfloor &&(*2)
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $a^* := b$ and $b^* = r$. We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big\lfloor \frac{r + b}{M} \Big\rfloor
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{a^* + b^*}{M} \Big\rfloor\\
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{a^*}{M} \Big\rfloor + \Big\lfloor \frac{(a^* \bmod M) + b^*}{M} \Big\rfloor &&(2)\\
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{b}{M} \Big\rfloor + \Big\lfloor \frac{(b \bmod M) + r}{M} \Big\rfloor\\
&= q' + \Big\lfloor \frac{r' + r}{M} \Big\rfloor &&(*3)
\end{aligned}
$$

Now

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{cases}
\text{if } M > 0 &\text{ then } 0 \leq r, r' < M \iff 0 \leq r + r' < 2M\\
\text{if } M < 0 &\text{ then } M < r, r' \leq 0 \iff 2M < r + r' \leq 0
\end{cases}\\
\\
&\begin{aligned}
&\equiv &&0 \leq \lvert r + r' \rvert < \lvert 2M \rvert\\
&&&\text{and } \big(r {+} r' {=} 0 \text{ xor } \operatorname{sgn}(r {+} r') {=} \operatorname{sgn}(S))\\
\\
&\equiv &&0 \leq \frac{r + r'}{M} < 2
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
$$

The ratio $\frac{r + r'}{M}$ is nonnegative because either $r {+} r' {=} 0$, in which case, the ratio is $0$, or $r {+} r'$ and $M$ have the same sign, in which case the ratio is positive.

We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big\lfloor \frac{r + r'}{M} \Big\rfloor
&=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } \frac{r + r'}{M} < 1\\
1 &\text{if } \frac{r + r'}{M} \geq 1
\end{cases}\\
&= \Big[\!\!\Big[ \frac{r + r'}{M} \geq 1 \Big]\!\!\Big]\\
&= \Bigg[\!\!\Bigg[
\begin{cases}
r + r' \geq M &\text{if } M > 0\\
r + r' \leq M &\text{if } M < 0
\end{cases}
\Bigg]\!\!\Bigg]\\
&= \Big[\!\!\Big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert \geq \lvert M \rvert\ \Big]\!\!\Big] &&(*4)
\end{aligned}
$$

Back to $(1)$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big\lfloor \frac{a + b}{M} \Big\rfloor
&= q + \Big\lfloor \frac{r + b}{M} \Big\rfloor &&(1)\\
&= q + q' + \Big\lfloor \frac{r' + r}{M} \Big\rfloor &&(3)\\
&= q + q' + \Big[\!\!\Big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert \geq \lvert M \rvert\ \Big]\!\!\Big] 
&&(4)(*5)\\
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{a}{M} \Big\rfloor + \Big\lfloor \frac{b}{M} \Big\rfloor + \Big[\!\!\Big[\ \big\lvert (a \bmod M) + (b \bmod M) \big\rvert \geq \lvert M \rvert\ \Big]\!\!\Big] 
&&(*6)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

### Proof of $\big\lceil \frac{a + b}{M} \big\rceil = q + q' + \big[\!\!\big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert > 0 \big]\!\!\big] + \big[\!\!\big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert > \lvert M \rvert\ \big]\!\!\big] \qquad \text{See}\ ^3$

We use the same definitions of $a, b, M \neq 0, q, r, q', \text{ and } r'$ as before.

For $x \in \mathbb R$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\big\lceil x \big\rceil
&=
\begin{cases}
\big\lfloor x \big\rfloor &x \in \mathbb Z\\
\big\lfloor x \big\rfloor + 1 &x \not \in \mathbb Z
\end{cases}\\
&= \big\lfloor x \big\rfloor + \Big[\!\!\Big[ x \not \in \mathbb Z \Big]\!\!\Big]\\
&= \big\lfloor x \big\rfloor + \Big[\!\!\Big[ x \bmod 1 \neq 0 \Big]\!\!\Big] &&(*7)
\end{aligned}
$$

Note that

$$
\begin{aligned}
(a + b) \bmod M
&= (qM + r + q'M + r') \bmod M\\
&= (r + r') \bmod M &&(*8)
\end{aligned}
$$

which means

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big[\!\!\Big[ (a + b) \bmod M \neq 0 \Big]\!\!\Big]
&= \Big[\!\!\Big[ (r + r') \bmod M \neq 0 \Big]\!\!\Big] &&(8)\\
&= \Big[\!\!\Big[ \big(r + r' \neq 0\big) \land \big(r + r' \neq M \big) \Big]\!\!\Big] &&\text{Since } &&0 \leq \lvert r + r' \rvert < \lvert 2M \rvert\\
&&&&&\text{and } \big(r {+} r' {=} 0 \text{ xor } \operatorname{sgn}(r {+} r') {=} \operatorname{sgn}(M) \big)\\
&= \Big[\!\!\Big[ r + r' \neq 0 \Big]\!\!\Big] \Big[\!\!\Big[ r + r' \neq M \Big]\!\!\Big] &&(*9)
\end{aligned}
$$

So

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big\lceil \frac{a + b}{M} \Big\rceil
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{a + b}{M} \Big\rfloor +
\Big[\!\!\Big[ \frac{a + b}{M} \not \in \mathbb Z \Big]\!\!\Big]
&&(7)\\
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{a + b}{M} \Big\rfloor +
\Big[\!\!\Big[ (a + b) \bmod M \neq 0 \Big]\!\!\Big]\\
&= q + q' +
\Big[\!\!\Big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert \geq \lvert M \rvert\ \Big]\!\!\Big] +
\Big[\!\!\Big[ r + r' \neq 0 \Big]\!\!\Big] \Big[\!\!\Big[\ r + r' \neq M \ \Big]\!\!\Big]
&&(5)(9)\\
&=
\begin{cases}
q + q' &\text{if } r + r' = 0\\
q + q' + 1 &\text{if } 0 < \lvert r + r' \rvert \leq \lvert M \rvert\\
q + q' + 2 &\text{if } \lvert M \rvert < \lvert r + r' \rvert < \lvert 2M \rvert\\
\end{cases}\\
&= q + q' +
\Big[\!\!\Big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert > 0\ \Big]\!\!\Big] +
\Big[\!\!\Big[\ \lvert r + r' \rvert > \lvert M \rvert\ \Big]\!\!\Big]
&&(*10)
\end{aligned}
$$

where, recall

$$
\begin{aligned}
q &:= \big\lfloor \frac{a}{M} \big\rfloor
&r &:= a \bmod M\\
q' &:= \big\lfloor \frac{b}{M} \big\rfloor
&r' &:= b \bmod M
\end{aligned}
$$

#### Example

For example, with $a = 8, b = 12.5, M = 5$, we have $q = 1, r = 3, q' = 2, r' = 2.5$. Substituting these values into $(10)$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\bigg\lceil \frac{8 + 12.5}{5} \bigg\rceil
&= 1 + 2 + \big[\!\!\big[ 3 + 2.5 > 0 \big]\!\!\big] + \big[\!\!\big[ 3 + 2.5 > 5 \big]\!\!\big] &&(10)\\
&= 3 + \big[\!\!\big[ 5.5 > 0 \big]\!\!\big] + \big[\!\!\big[ 5.5 > 5 \big]\!\!\big]\\
&= 3 + 1 + 1\\
&= 5
\end{aligned}
$$

which is correct as $\big\lceil \frac{8 + 12.5}{5} \big\rceil = \lceil 4.1 \rceil = 5$.

---

$^1$: See floored division in [Wikipedia's **Modulo operation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Variants_of_the_definition)

$^2$: See floored division in [Desmos's **5 types of integer division and their corresponding quotient, remainder, and Modulo operation**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j3a9ylwyze)

$^3$: Where $\big[\!\!\big[ condition \big]\!\!\big]$
denotes **Iverson bracket notation** and is defined as

$$
\Big[\!\!\Big[ condition \Big]\!\!\Big]
:=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } condition\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

---

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).